# Is it possible to fork multiple blockchains at the same time for testing smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain, infura, hardhat, ganache-cli

I am trying to fork ethereum, polygon, and arbitrum at the same time. I tried to use ganache-cli specifying different ports for each chain but it does not seem to grab the chain data when I use a different port. I am open to using hardhat, or anything else, but I was not able to specify a port with hardhat. Is anyone aware of a way to do this? Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible to configure in the hardhat.config file, however you could try starting [multiple hardhat local node instances](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/4477) each at their own port using the `hardhat node` cli command

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can fork multiple blockchains at the same time using hardhat just setup your networks in the hardhat config file and start your node on the terminal . If you have another network start a new terminal and start your node. You can refer to this [doc](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks) for more info

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and the linked docs doesn't have any details about forking multiple networks simultaneously.